# Does “interranima” mean “inner soul”?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, translation-check

I came across this on google translate and I love its sound…I would love to utilize this lovely word if indeed it does mean inner soul!

Comment: If you drop the second R in the word, you get a lot of modern organizations/groups/etc who use the word "interanima." It still doesn't mean "inner soul," but maybe the double R is a typo?

Answer (score 4):

No. *Anima* is the Latin word for soul, apart from that the word is not a proper Latin construction and it's not clear what it could mean. For what it's worth, *inter* means "between" or "among."

A straightforward translation of "inner soul" would be **interior anima** or **intima anima**. (*Intima* means something like "innermost.") A less generic translation may be possible depending on context.